# JQuery - Get value out of an input field inside hidden div

Tags: jquery

Will `$('#some-field').val()` return "something" or empty string? I assume it would return the value regardless if the div is visible or not. But I have been getting empty string. Any idea?

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <form>
        <input id="some-field" type="text" value="something" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Check if you have any other field/element with same ID. As others mentioned below, the val() should return you the value as long as it is in DOM.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I will continue to look into what's causing this strange behavior. But at least I am reassuring that my understanding was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div:hidden #some-field').val();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/173/)**

Even `$('#some-field').val();` will work also, because visibility doesn't effect, if the element belong to DOM.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/174/)**

Comment: You don't need additional filters if you going to select an element by ID.

Comment: @Vega hi mate, I know and I add to my answer

Answer (score 4):

It will return `something`. Visibility doesn't play a factor into retrieving values since it stills exist in the DOM.

Comment: I wish I can give two accepted answers. I up voted you instead. :)